# Xamarin Unable to Deploy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I was successfully using Xamarin Community Studio on OSX.  Today, my computer reported that Xamarin automatically updated.  Now, every time I try to deploy to an Android emulator I get the following error:

Deployment failed because of an internal error: There is not enough storage space on the device to store package: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24.apk.

I get this even when starting a new, blank project.  All of this is done through the IDE.  I have tried resizing the Android instance to a 4GB drive and 2GB of RAM, same error.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: It's not talking about RAM. It's talking about storage space. Debug builds of Xamarin apps about HUGE in comparison to java android apps. It's possible that you don't have enough space in the emulator to install the 50+MB application.

Answer (score 1):

I checked, doubled checked, and triple checked, but never found the "internal storage" field referred to by Jon Douglas.  However, I did find the answer on that screen.  I changed the "Target" to "API Level 24" and then it started working.  I think somewhere in there an error message got confused (i.e., it didn't allow it to copy Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24.apk, so Xamarin assumed that the reason was storage, when the real reason was an incompatible API).

Anyway, all seems well with the world now.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `-partition-size` in your AVD:

`emulator -partition-size 512 -avd MonoDroid`

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#There_is_not_enough_storage_space_on_the_device_to_deploy_the_package

You can read more about this here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

You can simply increase the internal storage setting here:

[image]

Comment: That's weird - mine doesn't have that option.  See my screenshot.

http://s12.postimg.org/g8ofsvicd/Screen_Shot_2016_09_27_at_5_04_06_PM.png

Comment: It should: http://content.screencast.com/users/JDouglas18/folders/Snagit/media/c207df5a-e153-4d34-b20c-9c0e324fbe25/2016-09-27_16-09-08.png

Try to ensure you bring the window down fully as it's not really optimized to show all the options for some reason on Mac. You may also need to update the SDK tools.